# standard deviation of two constant noised signals related through interpolation

Tags: image-processing, noise, interpolation, snr, statistics

Let us say say we have a noised constant signal and want to evaluate the standard deviation (std) of the noise. We calculate the std of the said noised signal and call it $\sigma_1$. Now we process the signal, by interpolating it and stretching it on a larger area and obtain a signal with more samples, which contains the same amount of information because we did interpolation. We calculate the standard deviation $\sigma_2$. How do they relate? Can we just compare them or do we need to make some adjustments based on the sample sizes. I get that $\sigma_2$ is less than $\sigma_1$ but it seems counterintuitive that the noise was reduced by just stretching the signal along with the noise.

Ok so let's us assume we have a DC signal 0.5 presented green and the noise is as follows
[image]

we then interpolate the signal and get the following signal
[image]

What we get is that the standard deviation in the first image is 0.3535 and in the second 0.2795, but what  I would like is to have more comparable standard deviation. We can't say that the lower image is less noised right?

Comment: What kind of interpolation are you thinking of? In terms of model (parametric ones?) and cost function?

Comment: What is a "noised constant signal "? Do you mean a DC signal with some noise on top of it or just stationary noise ?

Comment: Let's say a DC signal with some noise on top of it. Just stationary noise is also a generalization of the DC signal with some noise on top if it, right? Sorry that it was unclear.

Comment: Laurent Duval, assume that the interpolation is linear and that the signal is like an image. And then we stretch it (almost) uniformly in both directions.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Moreover, the images aren't constant and noise. For proper upsampling there shouldn't be any change in the energy of the noise. Up sampling can't be a method for Denoising (I wish it would, but there is no free meal).

Comment: @Royi hey Royi, yes I know that. So how do you show that the noise is the same? Because it is not shown by the standard deviation as we can see above. I assume that I am either missing a scaling constant factor in the formulae, or that the std is not the measure of the noise of the signal but some other variable.

Comment: It is easier to derive in 1D. But if you think about the frequency domain resampling just scales the axis. So think about a rectangle which its area is constant and you scale one edge so the other scales by the inverse factor to keep the area the same.